# Binding kendo UI tree view with kendo ui grid

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-ui-angular2, kendo-treeview

I am trying to bind a kendo grid with data from tree view node click. So when user clicks on node 'A' of tree view then grid should get populated with data corresponding to that node.
1. How do I update the grid data while traversing through tree. I am reading data from an array.
2. Is there a way to just update the data without recreating grid or resetting the grid.?

Comment: Please add what you try already, or just the base definition of the tree and grid

Comment: 2. `grid.dataSource.data(yourArrayHere)`

Comment: Are you still looking for an answer to this?